# Socket programming: How does client get access to its IP adress and port?

Tags: python, sockets, network-programming

Just started learning about socket programming using Python. To create server, we do something like this:

```
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
server_address = ('localhost', 10000)
sock.bind(server_address)
sock.listen(1)

while True:
    connection, client_address = sock.accept()
    ....
    ....
```

For client, we do something like this:

```
#client.py
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
server_address = ('localhost', 10000)
sock.connect(server_address)
....
....
```

I am not sure how to phrase my question but I was wondering about the mechanism behind client being assigned an IP address and port to connect to server. At server side, we explicitly `bind()`ed the socket to `localhost` address and port `10000`. We don't do this for client and yet client has its own IP address and port. How and at what level (OS?) does this happen? In fact, when we run `telnet localhost 10000`, we are able to talk to that server and server knows about the IP address and port of incoming connection. What is the mechanism behind it? How can I explore more about this stuff on my (Windows) machine?

Comment: This seems more to be a question regarding how Windows handles sockets than programming.

Comment: Are you asking how the client gets to know which server it wants to connect to?

Comment: @user56700 Platform/OS is irrelevant. I am willing to understand this from the point of view of any OS. If someone can explain this to me from POV of Unix, it'd still be great.

Comment: @Sören No. That is not what I want to know. I want to know the mechanism behind how client is assigned IP address and port as we never explicitly assign anything to client socket.